# Add row to table after a form submit without refresh - jquery ajax php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I've an ajax form and a table.

This is my ajax code :

```
$(function () {
    $(".submitann").click(function () {
        var title = $("#title").val();
        var announcement = $("#announcement").val();
        var dataString = $('#annform');

        if ((title == '') || (announcement == '')) {
            alert("Please Fill In The Fields");
        } else {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: dataString.serialize(),
                url: "http://www.domain.com/formprocess.php",
                success: function (data) {

                    //insert table code here

                });
            }
            return false;
        });

    });
```

I tried but failed. In the php code, I've done this :

```
$data = '<tr class="odd gradeX">
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxes" value="1" />
    </td>
    <td><a href="#" class="anntitle" data-type="text" data-pk="'.$id.'" data-original-title="Enter title"
        data-name="title">'.$_POST["title"].'</a>
    </td>
    <td><a class="delete" href="javascript:;">Delete</a>
    </td>
</tr>';

echo json_encode($data);
```

It works with many problems. 
Firstly, it goes to the last row. 
Second, the x-editables does not work.

How to add a row to the  without refreshing the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you need to give the id to your `<table id="mytable">`.than on success of ajax, add just like this:

```
var row_data = "";
row_data +="<tr class='odd gradeX'>
                                <td><input type='checkbox' class='checkboxes' value='1' /></td>
                                <td><a href='#' class='anntitle' data-type='text' data-pk=''.$id.'' data-original-title='Enter title' data-name='title' >'.$_POST['title'].'</a></td>
                                <td><a class='delete' href='javascript:;'>Delete</a></td>
                 </tr>";
$("#mytable").append(row_data);
```

Comment: it still goes to the last row and the jquery x-editables does not work. x-editables only work after refresh.

Comment: than where you want to add the new row ?

Comment: the new row will be added at the top. the first row of the table will be replaced by the new added record. Or do i have to use jquery to sort the table by date or primary id?. and i cant get any idea about the x-editable problem

Comment: if you want to add the data on to the starting of table than use prepend on the place of append in my code.and you can not sort the record by jquery, you have to use PHP for that.

Comment: It worked but do you have any idea for the x-editables? the jquery function is not working for the newly added row. Thank you

Comment: it should work , have you tried with prepend ? what error you are getting ?

Comment: Yea I tried with prepend. the jquery x-editables does not work at all. the content wont be editable like other rows. it will only work after a refresh.

Comment: the first row sorting problem got solved. but the x-editables problem remaining

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36344/discussion-between-harshal-mahajan-and-redzwan-latif)